# Show that if $\mathcal{M}$ is a model of $\Gamma$, and $\Delta \subseteq \Gamma$, then $\mathcal{M}$ is also a model of $\Delta$.

Tags: logic, proof-writing, solution-verification, model-theory

**Show that if $\mathcal{M}$ is a model of $\Gamma$, and $\Delta \subseteq \Gamma$, then $\mathcal{M}$ is also a model of  $\Delta$.**

Comment: Yes, it works fine.

Comment: I suggest you write a self answer to this question. It may seen superfluous, however another person will ask this question some day, and it would help if they can see the answer at the bottom of this page, after they google the question.

Comment: @user400188 Sure, will do!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. First, note that $\Gamma$ and $\Delta$ are sets of sentences.
2. Let's assume that $\mathcal{M}$ is a model of $\Gamma$, this means that $\mathcal{M} \models \varphi$ for every sentence $\varphi \in \Gamma$
3. Since $\Delta \subseteq \Gamma$, and $\Delta$ is a set of sentences, by def. $\subseteq$, every member of $\Delta$ is also a member of $\Gamma$
4. Then $\mathcal{M} \models \varphi$ for every $\varphi \in \Delta$
5. Therefore, $\mathcal{M}$ is a model of $\Delta$